# upload android local file to remote webserver using curl

Tags: android, linux, curl

I'm trying to upload a file from my android device using curl. The file is located at

> /sdcard/Download/fileToUpload.txt

Below is the command I use through [Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm&hl=en_us) application:-

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \            
                -F "content=@/sdcard/Download/fileToUpload.txt" \
                 http://192.168.1.104/android/upload.php
```

I have tested the same command which worked fine from desktop. 
I'm banging my head from past few hours. Please let me know what is wrong.

> *P.S: I'm worried where this question would be a stupid one.*
>
> edit:- I don't want to root my device. As this would be my last option.

Comment: using curl is a requirement?

Comment: Keeping in mind that I shouldn't root my device. I find curl .. no specific requirement. Is there any alternative to this?..

Comment: yes, you can use Retrofit

Comment: Ok.. actually I'm automating a shell script wherein I got into this curl scenario. . Can you drop in a good link for retrofit. I shall consider it if I need to rewrite my entire code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/), a very powerful library for Android, providing useful APIs to interface with servers through http requests.

In the specific case, you can use a post in multipart form data according to this template in an interface file

```
@Multipart
@POST("/android/upload.php")
Call<Void> sendFiles(
        @Part MultipartBody.Part[] files
);
```

Then, you have to instantiate retrofit in your specific code:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(endpoint)
            .build();
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and get back

Comment: I don't get how you'll be able to use Retrofit from command line

Comment: i gave this alternative solution since using curl or command line is not a strict requirement, according to the poster

Answer (score 0):

Curl library is installed on your desktop but this doesn't mean that the same library is installed on your android device (Terminal app runs on your device). To install curl library on an Android device you should probably have to root your device, download curl binaries and install them on the device. You can follow this guide to understand how: https://appuals.com/install-curl-openssl-android/

Comment: Came across this solution. But I don't want to root my device. This would be my last option to try for.. I see all the options used by curl are same as the desktop version..